# Error occurs when setting the current index of a react-virtualized List as state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, react-virtualized

**Problem**

I'm trying to put `startIndex` in state from within `onRowsRendered()`.

This works fine, *until* `CellMeasurer` is put into the mix.

When scrolling down and then up, the following error occurs:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

What causes this problem and what solves it?

**Demo**

- [with `CellMeasurer`](https://codesandbox.io/s/4j6663xyw) (error)
- [without `CellMeasurer`](https://codesandbox.io/s/nnpw2y9wlj) (no error)

**Code**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import faker from "faker";
import { List, CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache } from "react-virtualized";

import "./styles.css";

faker.seed(1234);

const rows = [...Array(1000)].map(() =>
  faker.lorem.sentence(faker.random.number({ min: 5, max: 10 }))
);

const App = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const rowRenderer = ({ key, index, style, parent }) => {
    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <div style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #eee", padding: ".5em 0" }}>
          {rows[index]}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{currentIndex}</h1>
      <p>
        <em>When scrolling down and then up, an error occurs. Why?</em>
      </p>
      <List
        height={400}
        width={600}
        rowCount={rows.length}
        rowHeight={35}
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        style={{ outline: "none" }}
        onRowsRendered={({ startIndex }) => {
          setCurrentIndex(startIndex);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: did you try using `Memo` ?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii Updated the first example to use `Memo`. Problem still occurs.

Comment: What if you put your virtual list inside another custom component, and update your currentIndex using props ? And then make your custom component pure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `rowRenderer` and `cellMeasurer` function outside of your Functional Component. Because It will be recreated every time your functional component is rendered.

**Functional Component:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/nnp9z3o9wj?fontsize=14

Or you can use **Class Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import faker from "faker";
import { List, CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache } from "react-virtualized";

import "./styles.css";

faker.seed(1234);

const rows = [...Array(1000)].map(() =>
  faker.lorem.sentence(faker.random.number({ min: 5, max: 10 }))
);

class VirtualList extends React.Component {


 rowRenderer = ({ key, index, style, parent }) => {
    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <div style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #eee", padding: ".5em 0" }}>
          {rows[index]}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
     return (
      <List
        height={400}
        width={600}
        rowCount={rows.length}
        rowHeight={35}
        rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
        style={{ outline: "none" }}
        onRowsRendered={this.props.setCurrentIndex}
      />
     )
   }
}

const App = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = React.useState(0);


  return (
    <>
      <h1>{currentIndex}</h1>
      <p>
        <em>When scrolling down and then up, an error occurs. Why?</em>
      </p>
      <VirtualList setCurrentIndex={setCurrentIndex} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Tried something [similar](https://codesandbox.io/s/n58pr6vzn0). Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: This is fascinating. [Tried implementing it using a `PureComponent`](https://codesandbox.io/s/98rkrnmomp), as you suggested, and it seems to be working! Can you explain why this works? Works with [local state in a PureComponent](https://codesandbox.io/s/8kkr61pj2l), too.

Comment: Even works [with a regular class component](https://codesandbox.io/s/jzx7yqk4m9)...

Comment: @Willem-Aart to tell you the truth, I am not sure why :D  Could it be because `rowRenderer` function is recreated every time in functional component ?

Comment: @Willem-Aart try to put `rowRenderer` outside your functional component

Comment: Great suggestion! Putting `cellMeasurerCache` outside of the function fixes the problem! It seems that `rowRenderer` can stay inside the function. Thank you so much for helping figuring this out!

Comment: @Willem-Aart you are welcome :) Could you mark it as a correct answer?